# How to estimate this power series

Tags: real-analysis

I need an upper bound of $$x\sum_{l=1}^\infty \left(x^{\frac{4^l}{2}}-x^{4^l}\right)$$ when $x$ is close to 1. Numerically, it shows that the an upper bound is 1/2. How can I show it analytically? Thanks!

Comment: Some people like to make their brain suffer :) 
Did you get anything interesting while searching for an answer? Relations, inequalities between term of the sequence that define your series?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a right proof but it gives an idea, I hope.

You can rewrite that as:
$$x\sum_{l=1}^\infty\left(x^{2^{2l-1}}-x^{2^{2l}}\right) = x\times(x^2 - x^4 + x^8 - x^{16} + \dots)= x\sum_{l=1}^\infty(-1)^{l+1}x^{2^l}$$

So, in a way, when $x\rightarrow1$, you get:
$$\sum_{l=1}^\infty(-1)^{l+1}$$
which is Grandi's series, evaluated to [1/2 with Cesàro sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series).

Comment: The thing is it doesn't have much sense in simple real analysis. I'm not sure the OP can use this, since the series of general term $(-1)^{i+1}$ doesn't converge

Comment: Your computation is incorrect: $x^{2^{2l-1}}-x^{2^{2l}}=x^{2^{2l-1}}(1-x^{2^{2l-1}})$.

Comment: No it's just a re-writing of the sum, with a change of index. The result is good, but maybe using a partial sum would have been clearer

Comment: OK, I see. Should have looked more carefully.